# Implement send devices feature from google chrome app in my own android app

Tags: android, google-chrome

Let me show the scenario:

[image: Compartir = Share]

[image]

I was looking for information about this google chrome app's feature ("send to your devices") because on my own app I need to send a link and open it in pc's browser in a easy way.

I thought it was an intent but reading documentation, I didn't find any similar info about it.

I know that some android's features are now "restricted" for non-system apps, but I'd like to ask if someone here know how to request permission to use this feature, in case is restricted, or maybe if there are other way to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, there are any other guy looking for this information, I have to say that I got the answer.

It's not an android feature, is a Google Cloud Platform feature.

You have to activate Chrome Management API, and then follow the documentation.